# JS и веб-сокеты - не удаётся отправить строку

Tags: javascript, websocket

```
var Socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:778");
Socket.onopen = function(){
    document.getElementById('Info').innerHTML = "Connection success!";
    Socket.send("Test");
};
```

Хендшейк с WS-сервером проходит нормально - отображается "Connection success!", но при выполнении `Socket.send("Test");` на сервер приходит не "Test", а каждый раз новый набор непонятных символов и браузер сам закрывает соединение с пометкой в консоли

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:778/' failed: Invalid frame
>   header

Следовал инструкции на https://learn.javascript.ru/websockets, где сказано, что для отправки просто:

> Выбираем, что переслать, и socket.send()

Оказалось ничего оно не просто...

**Как передавать данные из браузера на WS-сервер? Какие фрейм-хидеры он ждёт?**

Дополнительная информация:

[image: WS-Server]

**Почему на сервер приходит не "Test", а какая-то мешанина, да ещё и разной длины и каждый раз новая?**

Ещё пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кусок серверного кода:

```
$Data = socket_read($Socket, DATA_SIZE);
// Если на сокете нет данных, удаляем его из масива клиентских сокетов $Clients  и переходим к следующей итерации, иначе читаем данные
if ($Data === false){
    echo "No data...<br>";
    unset($Clients[$Socket_key]);
    continue;
}
else{$Data = rtrim($Data);}
if (strlen($Data) > 0){
    echo $Data.'<br>';
    switch ($Data[0]) {
        case 'G': // GET / HTTP ...
            $KeyStart = strpos($Data, WS_KEY_MARKER); // 'Sec-WebSocket-Key: '
            if ($KeyStart){
                $KeyStart += strlen(WS_KEY_MARKER);
                $SecureKey = substr($Data, $KeyStart, strpos($Data, 0x0D0A, $KeyStart) - $KeyStart - 1);
                $Handshake = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n"
                            ."Upgrade: websocket\r\n"
                            ."Connection: Upgrade\r\n"
                            ."Sec-WebSocket-Accept: ".base64_encode(sha1($SecureKey.WS_GIUD, true))."\r\n\r\n";
                socket_write($Socket, $Handshake);
            }
            else{
                socket_close($Socket);
                unset($Clients[$Socket_key]);
                break;
            }
            break;
        case 'T':
            socket_write($Socket, 'T: '.$Data);
            break;
        //...
        default:
            socket_write($Socket, $Data);
            break;
```

*PS: **с клиентом на С++ сервер работает отлично - все строки приходят как надо**, затык именно в клиенте-браузере.*

Comment: А зачем вы внутри Socket.onopen делаете вызов Socket.send? Вы создали новый Socket сделали подключение и вынесете этот вызов.

Comment: Я пробовал `setTimeout(function(){Socket.send("Test")},1000);` в конце скрипта - результат тот же

Comment: Пробуйте этот пример разобрать [пример](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393092/javascript-websockets-control-initial-connection-when-does-onopen-get-bound)

Comment: А какой максимальный размер пакета, отправляемого сервером в ответ?

Comment: Клиентский код у вас правильный. Смотрите что происходит на сервере.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, выложил часть серверного кода...

Comment: Почему вы думаете, что запрос всегда приходит к вам одним куском?

Comment: Возьмите да посмотрите (отладчиком или просто в консоль выведите) что именно приходит к вам на сервер.

Comment: Ну и почитайте про структуру вебсокет-сообщений.

Comment: Данные на сервер приходят в совершенно правильном формате согласно протоколу websocket. Почитайте спецификацию и поймёте, что с этим делать :) А лучше возьмите какую-нибудь готовую библиотеку для вебсокетов.

Comment: Но от С++ клиента ведь всё приходит нормально без танцев с бубном! Не понимаю почему одно и то же сообщение при заходе на сервер имеет разную длину и набор символов?

Comment: Может кто-то подскажет как парсить WS-сообщения?

Comment: Сокеты и вебсокеты — разные вещи, не надо их путать. В C++ клиенте у вас сокеты, а в браузере вебсокеты

Comment: @andreymal, да, уже понял

Answer (score 0):

Функции кодирования/декодирования сообщений WebSocket в данной теме:

https://habrahabr.ru/post/209864/

Всем спасибо за проявленный интерес.